# Using template with a void function

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to use c++ template generics with a void function,

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
inline void swap(T& x, T& y)
{
    T temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

int main() 
{
    cout << "Swapper!" << endl;
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    swap(x, y);
    cout << x << y;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives an error:

**call of overloaded swap() is ambiguous**

How do I remove this error?

Comment: I think the duplicate does not fully address why `std::swap` can be an issue even though neither `<algorithm>` nor `<utility>` are included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `using namespace std;` because this namespace *already contains a function called [`swap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/)* and the compiler doesn't know which one to choose. To be honest, you don't really need to write such a function yourself, it has already been done for you.

Another way is to rename your function to something other than `swap`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `using namespace std;`. You should almost never use this line *anywhere* in your code. A good approach is to instead just quality all `std` names, i.e. write `std::cout << "Swapper!" << std::endl;` instead of `cout << "Swapper!" << endl;`.

In this particular case, your own `swap` function conflicts with `std::swap`, which you indirecty get via `<iostream>`. While `std::swap` is only *guaranteed* to exist in `<algorithm>` and `<utility>`, all C++ standard headers are allowed to pull in any other C++ standard headers.

So once you include *any* standard header, `using namespace std;` creates a potential conflict with *all* names in `std`.